# PHP nohup process randomly stops

Tags: php, bash, nohup, php-resque

I have a php-redis process which is running in the background and 99% of the time it works perfectly and continues to run. However, every so often the process just dies without any reason. There is nothing in any of the logs, the server does not run out of processing power, ram, etc.

It is being started with a bash script and is run with nohup.

Anyone have any ideas? I have been debugging this for days and am out of ideas. I can provide more information if you need it.

Comment: What happens if PHP can not reach the Redis server, are you catching the errors, and/or are you redirecting STDERR to STDOUT in your nohup logs?

Comment: Php is not connecting to the server in this case. It is a resque job which is always polling the server every 5 seconds and will reconnect if it can't connect to it. However, your comment did make me think of something else which I will check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, I would certainly recommend using supervisor to manage the process. It will ensure the process is always running/waiting, and will automatically restart it on failure.

Comment: I will look into this and see if it can be applied to a Resque job, thanks.

Comment: Was able to get it working with the help of this post http://shanedowling.com/manage-background-tasks-php-resque-supervisor/. Doesn't solve my problem of why it stops but will re-start it if it does. Thanks for your help.